# как читать формат числа

Tags: python, pandas

[![применив метод describe() к датасету pandas, я получила статданные по столбцу в виде числа+2цифры - как читать этот формат и что означает этот + ?
прилагаю скрин столбца][1]][1]

например
count   3.928400e+04

Comment: Скрин не прикрепили

Comment: Это обычный научный или экспоненциальный формат числа. Ne+M означает N * 10**(+M)

Comment: Грубо говоря `1.0e+03` (или `1e3`) это `1000`. Для относительно близких по модулю к 1 чисел это не очень удобно, но для очень больших или очень маленьких (близких к нулю) - это более приемлемая запись, чем куча нулей в конце или куча нулей после запятой.